#  How to preserve case using re.IGNORECASE and .sub?

Tags: python, regex

```
import re

def bold_partial(long_string, partial):

    replacer = re.compile(partial, re.IGNORECASE)
    new_long_string = replacer.sub('<b>' + partial + '</b>', long_string)
    print new_long_string


bold_partial('My name is Roger the Shrubber. I arrange, design, and sell shrubberies.', 'roger the shrubber')
```

Returns:
My name is **roger the shrubber**. I arrange, design, and sell shrubberies.

I'd like to return the original case:

My name is **Roger the Shrubber**. I arrange, design, and sell shrubberies.

Sorry, but I'm a total noob.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def bold_partial_rep(matchobj):
    return '<b>' + matchobj.group(0) + '</b>'

def bold_partial(long_string, partial):
    replacer = re.compile(partial, re.IGNORECASE)
    new_long_string = replacer.sub(bold_partial_rep, long_string)
    print new_long_string
```

Or if you want to shorten code you can get rid of the new function and use the following line in `bold_partial()`:

```
new_long_string = replacer.sub(lambda m: '<b>%s</b>' % m.group(0), long_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a function to `.sub()` that returns the appropriate replacement instead, or look at group #0.